# Convergence of a particular summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does summation $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^{a}}$$ converge if $a>1$?

Comment: Use the Integral Test.

Comment: Yes, integral from $2$ to $\infty$ of $\frac{1}{x\ln^a x}\,dx$ converges, so our series converges.

Comment: Yes it does. Integral Test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The convergence property easily follows from [Cauchy Condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) .

**Edit:** In more detail, the suggested series has the same convergence properties as

$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{2^n\left(\log2^n\right)^a}{}={}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^a\left(\log2\right)^a}{}={}\dfrac{1}{\left(\log2\right)^a}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^a}
$$

which, being a $p$-series, converges for $a>1$.

Answer (score 2):

The integral test will also do the job easily.

$$\int_2^\infty {dt \over t \log(t)^a} = \int_{\log(2)}^\infty {dt \over t^a}.$$

Do not use $n = 1$ or you will have a domain annoyance.

Comment: It already was.